# getting a Python program to display JSON data

Tags: python, json

I am trying to access a JSON value from a python script. the value I am trying to access is "name" only, would really appreciate help in how can I do that using a python script  the JSON data file is:

```
"restaurants": [
{
  "restaurant": {
    "R": {
      "res_id": 9101083
    },
    "id": "9101083",
    "name": "My Meat Wagon",
    "url": "https://www.zomato.com/dublin/my-meat-wagon-smithfield?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1",
    "location": {
      "address": "Market Square, Smithfield, Dublin Dublin 7",
      "locality": "Smithfield",
      "city": "Dublin",
      "city_id": 91,
      "latitude": "53.3489980000",
      "longitude": "-6.2788120000",
      "zipcode": "Dublin 7",
      "country_id": 97,
      "locality_verbose": "Smithfield, Dublin"
    },
```

in my test.py file I have

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    data["restaurant"]["name"]
    print data
```

what should I do do have the program get the name of a restaurant only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply writing `data["restaurant"]["name"]` doesn't *do* anything meaningful with the dictionary yet, it just looks it up, returns the value and then does nothing with it. In particular, it does not change what `data` refers to. If you wanted that, you would have to write:

```
data = data["restaurant"]["name"]
```

I don't recommend doing that though, because you lose the ability to access anything else inside the json structure. Instead, just print the value:

```
print data["restaurant"]["name"]
```

Comment: Thank, I got it to work to display  one place, when I add a second JSON object to the file and try to run the program I am getting :    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
 my current JSON file is :  `    {
      "restaurant": {
        "R": {
          "res_id": 9101083
        },
        "name": "My Meat Wagon"
      }
    },
    {
      "restaurant": {
        "R": {
          "res_id": 9101628
        },
        "name": "Wowburger"
      }
    }
    `